# Flask: how to serve an updating log file line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask

There are two threads in my Python program, one is for flask, and the other one is for the background task and it will dynamically generate some logs strings into a log file when it is running.

I've tried streaming the file with `yield` like this:

```
@app.route('/task_status')
def get_background_task_log():
    def read_task_log():

        # Try load log files
        log_file = open("/tmp/task_log.log", "r")

        # Stream file to the client
        while True:
            new_line = log_file.readline()

            # Stream the file to the client until it ends.
            if "Foo: process finished!" in new_line:
                yield new_line.encode("utf-8")  # Flush the last line
                break

            yield new_line.encode("utf-8")

    return Response(read_task_log(), mimetype="text/plain",
                    headers={"Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=task_log.log"})
```

But when Chrome loads `/task_status`, it just hangs there and wait until the line `Foo: process finished` come out, instead of show me the content line by line. I've also tried removing the `Content-Disposition` header and it stays the same.

Meanwhile I've also tried using `send_file()` but it can only returns a partial log file when I access it from Chrome.

What should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

Check out pygtail on github.

> [Pygtail](https://github.com/bgreenlee/pygtail) reads log file lines that have not been read. It will even
>   handle log files that have been rotated.

From their example:

```
from pygtail import Pygtail

for line in Pygtail("some.log"):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```